# Q: js file showing me the content instead executing it

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, backend

I installed node on my web host but when I enter for example :
[www.example.com:3000/server.js](http://www.example.com:3000/server.js)
it's showing me the file content instead of executing it
and ***giving me timeout!***
**Source:**

```
const http = require('http');
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer(function (req, res){
    res.write('Hello node')
    res.end
})

server.listen(port,function (error){
    if (error) {
        console.log('err',error)
    }else {
        console.log('server port',port)
    }
})
```

**the output from the website:**

```
const http = require('http');
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer(function (req, res){
    res.write('Hello node')
    res.end
})

server.listen(port,function (error){
    if (error) {
        console.log('err',error)
    }else {
        console.log('server port',port)
    }
})
```

***The output from the console:***

```
server port 3000
```

***What should the output be:***

```
Hello node
```

***note:***

- I did lunch it with node and entered the ports*

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Have you tried to browse just `www.example.com:3000` ?

Comment: yeah I tried and it's giving me time out

Comment: Ok, thanks for trying. I just used node.js with express. But i would guess that you have to define a route like `/` (root) somehow.

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me,but how I define it because I'm not a pro node I'm PHP

Comment: The time out is due to `res.end` being a method `res.end()`.

Comment: @Daniel I did what you said and still not working, is there anything else to do instead of the js file and running node comman ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is when I called the support of godaddy.com I gave him the issue, after checking my hosting he says that my hosting plan not supporting root or super user, and node.js requires superuser privileges, so by the end i want to thank all of the people who tried to help me, thank you so much.